# Телеграм бот. (Python, Telebot)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Начал знакомство с написанием телеграм ботов. Возникла сложность при обмене сообщениями из канала в бота.
Алгоритм:
Пользователь выполняет команду /check после нее появляется некое сообщение в телеграм канале, я хочу ответить на данное сообщение (reply в группе или комментарий в канале к данному посту), и ответ должен отобразиться у пользователя, отправившего команду /check.

```
    current_posts = {}
@bot.message_handler(commands=['check'])
def check(message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_name = get_user_name(user_id)

    if user_name:
        # Создаем пост в канале и сохраняем его message_id
        post_message = bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, f'Поступила новая работа от {user_name}!')
        post_id = post_message.message_id

        # Сохраняем информацию о посте и его авторе
        current_posts[post_id] = {
            'user_id': user_id,
            'user_name': user_name,
            'channel_id': CHANNEL_ID,
            'original_message_id': post_id  # Добавляем информацию об исходном сообщении
        }

        # Запрашиваем у пользователя необходимые данные
        bot.send_message(user_id, 'Пожалуйста, введите следующую информацию: \n Гос. номер или VIN автомобиля \n ID терминала \n Комментарий к выполненной работе')
        # Настраиваем обработчик для ответа пользователя на запрос
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_user_data, post_id)

    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Поступила новая работа от неизвестного пользователя (ID: {user_id})')

# Обработчик для обработки ответа пользователя и добавления комментария к исходному сообщению
def process_user_data(message, post_id):
    user_data = message.text
    user_id = current_posts[post_id]['user_id']
    user_name = current_posts[post_id]['user_name']
    channel_id = current_posts[post_id]['channel_id']
    original_message_id = current_posts[post_id]['original_message_id']


    bot.edit_message_text(f'Поступила новая работа от {user_name}!\n'
                          f'Пользователь {user_name} отправил следующие данные: {user_data}',
                          chat_id=channel_id,
                          message_id=original_message_id)
```

Данный код работает правильно: создается пост в канале, редактируется в последствии данными о ТС.

Модуль ответа на сообщение в канале:

```
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def handle_message(message):
    if message.reply_to_message:
        original_message_id = message.reply_to_message.message_id
        user_id = message.from_user.id
        user_name = get_user_name(user_id)

        if user_name:
            user_data = message.text

            
            if original_message_id in current_posts:
                original_post_data = current_posts[original_message_id]
                original_user_id = original_post_data['user_id']
                original_user_name = original_post_data['user_name']



                # Отправляем ответ в бота
                bot.send_message(original_user_id, f'В вашем сообщении получен ответ от {user_name}: {user_data}')
```

Прошу помочь с тем, чтобы комментарии под постом уходили автору поста в бота.